# adding ellipsis to a sortable mat table

Tags: css, html-table, angular-material, ellipsis, angular-material-table

I'm currently using a sortable `mat-table`, I added ellipsis to it so that when there is enough space the full text is shown otherwise the text gets truncated. For the table cells it works fine, however for the header cells no ellipsis is added.

I read also somewhere that ellipsis behavior doesn't work good with sortable tables. Any work around?

[This is an example with similar code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rd9qkz-2vgba8?file=app/table-basic-example.html).

Columns that do not have sorting gets truncated as expected. The first column where sorting is applied doesn't truncate text as expected.

If I add a `<div>` around the `header content` and apply a `max-width` to it, it works; unfortunately this is fixed value.

The other problem is that it doesn't show the full text when there is space as with the `mat-cells`.